# Cloning java application on Windows

Tags: java, windows, runtime, javafx-8

I am trying to start a new process with Runtime.exec() from my javafx application.
The new process is my javafx application (but in a new process, the "parent" one will still be open).

So I run javaw via the exec method and tell it my classpath. And here is my problem: the classpath contains whitespaces, so I need to quote every path. But I retrieve the path at runtime via java.class.path (since it is the same application).

Do I need to process the string and quote everything or is there an easy way to get this to work?

Here is the code:

```
public static void startInNewProcess() {
    try {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        File javaPath = new File(System.getProperty("java.home"), "bin/javaw");
        File classPath = new File(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
        System.out.println("java loc: " + javaPath.toString());
        System.out.println("classpath: " + classPath);
        Process p = r.exec(javaPath.toString() + " -classpath " + classPath.getPath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get the following string as classpath:

```
classpath: C:\Users\kwilhelm\git\ResourcePlaner\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.jfx8_2.0.0.201506111511.jar;C:\Users\kwilhelm\git\ResourcePlaner\lib\itextpdf-5.5.6-javadoc.jar;C:\Users\kwilhelm\git\ResourcePlaner\lib\itextpdf-5.5.6-sources.jar;C:\Users\kwilhelm\git\ResourcePlaner\lib\itextpdf-5.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kwilhelm\git\ResourcePlaner\lib\controlsfx-8.40.9.jar
```

But javaw gives the error that it can't find mainclass "Files", so it can't handle the whitespace in the path.

So is there a way to get the classpath with quotes?
Is there a better solution?

Any help is apreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And here is my problem: the classpath contains whitespaces, so I need to quote every path.

Actually, no you don't.

And in fact, if you do attempt to quote every path, it is likely to mess up bigtime, because `exec` doesn't understand shell quoting.

What you actually need to do is this:

```
    Process p = r.exec(new String[] {javaPath.toString(),
                                     "-classpath",
                                     classPath.getPath()});
```

This tells `exec` exactly where the boundaries of the command arguments are, so that it doesn't need to try (and fail) to figure it out for itself.

In fact, that still isn't right.  You also need to add:

- any other JVM options that the cloned instance needs,
- a class name, and
- any arguments required after the classname.

The classname is mandatory.  (You left it out, and that is why the `java` command was outputting its help message!)

Comment: Thx for the fast answer, but when I change my code to yours, javaw only prints out its help. Could the classpath returned by System.getProperty("java.class.path") be wrong?

Comment: Actually, the problem is that you haven't told Java which class to run.